# Converting audio (mp3->ogg) on an Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mp3, ogg

I'm creating a **music chart app**.

As an audio player I want to use **html5 audio**, but there is a problem.

First of all not all browsers support **mp3** with **html5 audio**.

I want to ask:

Is it a good idea to convert audio from **mp3** to **ogg** on a server?

Because, I want to allow users upload only **mp3 files**, and then I will convert that **mp3 file to ogg** format and store both of them on the server.
I can not imagine, how much resources (CPU, RAM) will be required for such a process.

As the second variant I think to use **jPlayer**, which supports flash solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert mp3 to ogg with ffmpeg.

Yo can convert online the stream, and publish 2 stream, with mp3 and ogg

Jose